# OpenGL ES 2: Should I use glMultiTexCoord or glVertexAttribPointer?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm starting to code in openGL ES 2 after several months of doing it in openGL ES 1, and though I'm reading a lot of resources, there are some things I don't understand.

One is this:
For loading an array of texture coordinates, should I use glMultiTexCoordX or glVertexAttribPointer?
Because If I'm not wrong, I can do it either way, so what's the reason glMultiTexCoordX exists?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

glMultiTexCoord* doesn't exist in OpenGL ES 2.0, only glVertexAttribPointer, so use it for all your vertex attributes.

Comment: How? Could you please reference a doc with examples on how to set texture coordinates with it?

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro I'm interested in that as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time, but I still wanna comment this question due to I stuck with same problem. There isn't such method in openGLES version as Matias said. use glVertexAttribPointer instead, here is a instruction:
http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-seven-an-introduction-to-vertex-buffer-objects-vbos/

Here is simple code to achieve what glMultiTexCoord in openGLES:

```
// Pass in the position information
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, POSITION_DATA_SIZE,
GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mCubePositions);
```

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).